# It is possible to replay CAN bus messages for building intercom system?

Tags: can

I would like to automate my apartment's intercom unit to unlock the building door remotely. I am able to press the door unlock button at any time and this unlocks the door in the lobby. I scoured the internet and was able to find the unit as a wholesale in China and the documentation mentions the communication protocol is CANbus.

I took the cover off my video intercom unit and found that there is a single DATA pin which I presume is transmit or maybe a single wire implementation of CAN? Impossible to tell.

I measured the voltage by connecting a multimeter to ground and to the DATA pin. It was 14.5v which seems rather strange. When I press a button I can see the voltage drop slightly.

Are there any tools I could use to see the messages being generated by the intercom unit? Ideally I would like to reverse engineer the CAN messages and then replay them from a WiFi enabled micro controller so I can remotely operate.

Comment: If you cannot borrow an oscilloscope, there are cheap USB logic analysers (8 inputs, 24MHz) suitable for that, but of course, it will fry if voltage exceeds 5V.

Comment: You will need to know which standard of CAN is being used. Then you can buy/make a dongle to connect the bus to your computer. Using a language of your choice you can start communicating with the bus. (for example `python-can` library)

Comment: Doesn't sound like the pin you found have anything to do with CAN whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canbus is not normally single wire, equally the voltage makes it seem more like K-line / L-line, if that is the case you should be able to hook it up to a PC serial port and log it at 10400 baud, (CANbus is usually too fast for reliable single wire transfer over the kind of distances a home intercom would work at)

It is 100% possible to replay messages, just in this case depends a little on the implementation, e.g. if it uses some kind of rolling code (unlikely) to prevent replay messages from being valid.

Have a look at where that data pin connects to inside the device, usually there will be a little 8 pin IC that acts as a tranciver for the data bus, this should give you a very solid tell tale of exactly what physical layer it is using (could alternatively just be a transistor),

And finally, if it is K-line, you will need to offset the voltage of any logic analyser you may hook up to it at a later stage, low is below 33% of VCC, and high is above 66%, so for your 14.5V bus you want to offset near the middle for reliable capture from some of the weirder devices.

Edit: Adding image of suggested transceiver schematic.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I opened up the unit and on the PCB I can't follow the DATA pin :(. I tried using the continuity function of the multimeter to see where it connects to was not lucky.

Here is the PCB: https://share.icloud.com/photos/0YPziGmGKkwPG-8WTkW2pL4JA#St_Leonards

Comment: If I had to guess, it connects to Q18 directly to the left of it, with the resistor between them acting as the pullup to 14.5V,

Comment: If this is the case, its practically the same physical standard as K-line, but the varient that is compatible with logic analysers, you may still have luck trying 10400 baud or similar with a serial power RX pin if you lack any other tools to see what is being sent.

Comment: I tried the continuity function on all the components around Q18. Did not get a continuity beep but saw some voltage(?) values on the multimeter. Apologies for the amateurism but when you say connect to to serial RX... Would I be able to say for example configure an rPi to enable a serial port on the GPIO pints and then step down the voltage to 3.3v? Then open a capture of the serial device using screen or something like that?

Comment: That would work, just us a resistor divider to reduce the voltage to about 3V, something like 4.7K between the data line and the Pie GPIO, and a 1.2K resistor between the GPIO and ground, 

There will also be other example code for the pie to log the state of the pin to work as a kind-a logic analyser if push comes to shove.

Comment: Makes sense... This then begs the next question: presuming I can hack together a python script to replay the serial messages, how can I step up the voltage to the ~14-15v logic level?

Comment: My suspicion is that you will just need to ground the data line with an NPN transistor to pull it down with a pullup in either or both devices keeping it idling high, you would want a current limiting resistor between the base of the transistor and the pie GPIO, e.g. 1K, transistor collector to the data line, emitter to ground,

Comment: Thanks but I am having a hard time following the circuitry. Would it be too much to ask to draw a crude diagram? I'm trying to reproduce in EveryCircuit

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/ybwzse7f

Comment: I was able to connect and capture serial data. You were right in that connecting to an RS232 port with 9600b appears to work. I get the correct messages for START and END on each packet but from there I would like to start reverse engineering the message structure. More info [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24843/reverse-engineering-12-byte-serial-packets-from-doorbell).

Comment: Cannot comment there yet, so could you flesh out that question, such as what button or button sequence is causing what message?

Comment: I started building the circuit as you kindly suggested, however it appears the voltage I'm getting on the RX line is only 1.8 - 1.9v (which is what is expected). Is that enough for the UART logic level to understand high/low pulses?

Comment: Increase the resistance of the resistor to ground on the rx wire. To increase the voltage closer to about 3V.

Comment: I built a little breadboard unit with an rPi zero and hooked it up. Luckily nothing burnt out which is a good start. I wrote a small nodejs application that would allow me to send and receive serial data. The issue is that on the serial receive side I get a constant flow of zeros. This happens if a power the rPi from the USB port and connect to the circuit I built and not connect anything else. If I short the TXD and the RXD pin directly on the rPi 0 I can send and receive messages no problems. Any ideas what could be causing that? Thanks!

Comment: Here is the breadboard in case that helps: https://www.icloud.com/photos/#0LgpDJBQ_mjjvfIdTcCuoO36A

Comment: Hard to interpret your breadboard, I have updated my answer with what I think the circuit should be like, the left resistor is what is in other devices in the bus, you do not need to add it.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram. I don’t quite follow what you mean by the left resistor being in the other devices in the bus. Which resistor are you referring to? My breadboard circuit has all the resistors indicated.

Comment: sorry the right most 1K, I'm left-right disoriented.

Comment: I've implemented the circuit on the breadboard and raspberry pi. Here is the diagram: https://i.ibb.co/nrVy14m/intercom-1.png

Unfortunately only the RXD appears to work. If I disconnect the TXD pin I can see all messages on the bus and decode everything going on in the building. However If I connect TXD pin, I can't see anything. Sending commands also doesn't seem to do anything. Fun process nonetheless!

Comment: Ok, guessing your TX might be set as idle high, you may need to invert that in your settings.

Comment: Sadly from what I can tell, you cannot change the idle characteristics on the built in UART on the rPi. What may work however is using a software UART implementation to directly drive arbitrary GPIO pins. Looking into that with: http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html

Comment: I found a very useful post here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=233442#p1431135 (appears to be a software UART and somebody has kindly modified to support inverted logic). Not sure if thats what I want? Will that invert all 0s to 1s or simply the IDLE state?

Comment: I am also wondering if adding a second GPIO pin to simply switch on the TXD line just before transmission would work? Something like the following: http://tinyurl.com/y86yc79l